# bloom pulls in older tagged version

Tags: ros, github, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I'm making a release using `bloom` I noticed on the commandline that it pulled in an older tagged version. Why is that, and how can I make a release with the newest tagged version?

I manually made a release "0.8.0" on [moveit_core](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_core/releases) github website (I thought I had to manually do so without using `catkin_prepare_release`, only because I had to increment from 0.6.15 to 0.8.0 for jade, which I had no idea how to achieve(*1)). But bloom wants to use 0.7.1, which is one older tag (and should be used for indigo but not for jade).

Not sure how related this is but looking at [the list of releases page](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_core/releases), comparing with other repositories where the latest tag I made by catkin_prepare_release, I noticed that the one I made manually (0.8.0 on moveit_core) seems highlighted, while in other repositories they look the same as older tags.

---

UPDATE *1 `catkin_prepare_release` has an option to allow specifying the new versions e.g. `--bump` or `--version`. See its help doc by `-h`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234638/bloom-pulls-in-older-tagged-version/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2016-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is your track configuration in bloom set to the correct branch?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-05-18**:
You're right; [it was pointing to a wrong branch](https://github.com/ros-gbp/moveit_core-release/blob/b0c5fc3b75fc722874595ee6c70073f15ae03608/tracks.yaml#L81) and now it starts working as expected after I corrected with `--edit` option of bloom.